# Johansen cointegration, VAR, VECM

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I do have a question regarding Johansen's cointegration, VAR, and VECM model estimation. I would like to analyze the relationship between two variables using these methods. My dataset consists of 4 countries and 25 years for each country. Is it possible to use these methods or should I use some replacements? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: All would seem relevant if you had a single country. With 4 of them, some panel version of cointegration analysis might be more relevant.